# how to enable portfolio in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, themes, portfolio

is there any way to active portfolio section by adding some code to functions of theme ?
i saw some themes that have this feature , that themes add a new section named portfolio to back-end of Word-press

Comment: what? didn't get my answer? Feel free to ask if you have any questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) to accomplish what you want.

> WordPress can hold and display many different types of content. A
>   single item of such a content is generally called a post, although
>   post is also a specific post type. Internally, all the post types are
>   stored in the same place, in the wp_posts database table, but are
>   differentiated by a column called post_type.

### PHP EXAMPLE:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Portfolios' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio' )
      ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

Then to add it in your theme you can use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

EDIT:

### WP_Query Example

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'portfolio'
); // these arguments are telling WP_Query to only look for the post types called portfolio.
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    the_post_thumbnail();
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->
```

Ask me for any confusions.

**NOTE:** I am showing you a method without using any plugins. A custom approach.

Comment: thanks Dear Faiz Ahmed . I get your answer now because our house network had some problems .

Comment: excuse me , can you code me a simple one i couldn't do that :( i don't know any thing about querys

Comment: @AminPoursaied See the edited question and ask me for any confusions

Comment: are you have yahoo messenger id ? if you have please add me id:rapidrockets

Comment: no , but i think you have a google account for using hangouts ? if you have send me a message amin.poursaied @ gmail.com